# Decrypting an SQLCipher .db File on Mac

Tags: database, macos, encryption, macos-sierra, sqlcipher

I have an encrypted SQLCipher .db file but i don't have the PRAGMA key.
How can I decrypt the file and access it without a key for it?
There are examples for windows here but none for Mac and honestly I'm not a command line expert so if anyone can share how this is done I would be greatful.

I'm running MacOS Sierra.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I encrypt the file and access it without a key for it?

Without the key used to encrypt the content of a SQLCipher database, you can not decrypt the content of the database.